# Get values from php loop and multiple those values on keyup

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

I have a PHP loop created dynamically with two text boxes and one result column.

What i need is , just multiple the values entering first two boxes and show result in its near Result box.

The PHP loop

```
<?php
 $sql=$db->query("SELECT * FROM calc");
 foreach($sql as $row)
 {
  ?>
<div class="calc">
 <input type="text" id="txt1id<?= $row['id'] ?>" onkeyup="multiple()">
 <input type="text" id="txt2id<?= $row['id'] ?>" onkeyup="multiple()">
 <input type="text" id="resultid<?= $row['id'] ?>" title="Result shows here automatically">
</div>
<?php } ?> // loop ends here.
```

And script is

```
<script>
 function multiple()
 { 
    // how to get two different variables like this with different id to multiple ?
    var firstBox = parseInt(document.getElementById(firstid).value);
    var secondBox = parseInt(document.getElementById(secondid).value);


 }
</script>
```

Comment: where you need php values ? or where is php loop ?

Comment: the `div class='calc' ` is created by php loop , the php table contain other values but not included here, here the ids are getting from database..like `txt1id1,txt2id1` etc.

Comment: can you share php code also ?

Comment: please check edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass row id to the function like this

```
<div class="calc">
 <input type="text" id="txt1id<?= $row['id'] ?>" onkeyup="multiple(<?= $row['id'] ?>)">
 <input type="text" id="txt2id<?= $row['id'] ?>" onkeyup="multiple(<?= $row['id'] ?>)">
 <input type="text" id="resultid<?= $row['id'] ?>" title="Result shows here automatically">
</div>
```

And change in JS like below

```
<script>
 function multiple(rowid)
 { 
    var firstBox = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1id"+rowid).value);
    var secondBox = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2id"+rowid).value);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: `var secondBox = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1id"+rowid).value);` , txt1id must be `txt2id` ..right ?

Comment: Also check rowid in console inside function `console.log("Row id :"+rowid);`

Comment: you did great and fast..i will check